# Can someone share the Mule official link to download Data-weave plugin patch for Mule Runtime Version 3.9.0 Community Edition?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

In this https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Runtime-Security-Update-February-22-2021 page a Data-weave plugin patch of Mule Runtime Version 3.9.0 is enlisted as a fixation of "Server Side Request Forgery affecting Mule runtimes in certain use cases". But the patch jar is not available in given link https://help.mulesoft.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0682T000008XHSw. Can anyone help to get the workable link to download the mentioned patch jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. MuleSoft only distributes patches for the Enterprise Edition (ie the commercial version). The reason you can not use the link is that you need to be a customer of the Enterprise Edition. Even if you could access it, trying to use a patch for a different version or edition may cause unexpected failures.

Comment: Can you please confirm that <https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-1630> (XML external entity (XXE) vulnerability) and <https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-1627> (Server Side Request Forgery vulnerability) issues are affecting Mule Community Edition or not?

Comment: If you read the articles it says only that Mule 3.x and 4.x released before June 8, 2021 and Mule 3.8.x,3.9.x,4.x runtime released before February 2, 2021 are affected. It doesn't mention if it affects Community Edition.